# Problema al hacer una peticiónFocus en un EditText

Tags: java, android, xml

Estoy teniendo un problema para solicitar un `focus` después de hacer algo en mi actividad, pero no estoy seguro en dónde estoy fallando.

**Les dejo mi codigo**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayoutcarga_manual_activity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview_cargamanual_activity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/act_carga_manual_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_carga_manual_1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="23dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title_article_carga_manual"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#70273D"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Artículo: " />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_article_traspaso_manual"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:hint="Artículo" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/searchbuttontoactivity"
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/search"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_carga_manual_2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linear_carga_manual_1" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title_cantidad_carga_manual"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#70273D"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="Cantidad: " />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title_cantidad_cajas_carga_manual"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:text="Cajas: " />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edit_cantidad_cajas_traspaso_manual"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="numberSigned|number|numberDecimal"
                    android:ems="3"
                    android:maxLength="6"
                    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                    android:hint="0" />
            </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                 android:id="@+id/linear_carga_manual_3"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linear_carga_manual_2"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/linear_carga_manual_2" >

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/title_cantidad_unidades_carga_manual"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                     android:text="Unidades: " />

                 <EditText
                     android:id="@+id/edit_cantidad_unidades_traspaso_manual"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:ems="3"
                     android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                     android:hint="0"
                     android:inputType="numberSigned|number|numberDecimal" >

                 </EditText>
             </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                 android:id="@+id/linear_carga_manual_3_5"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignRight="@+id/linear_carga_manual_3"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/linear_carga_manual_3"
                 android:visibility="gone" >

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/title_unidadescaja_carga_manual"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                     android:text="UnidadesCaja: " />

                 <EditText
                     android:id="@+id/edit_unidadescaja_traspaso_manual"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:ems="3"
                     android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                     android:hint="0"
                     android:inputType="numberSigned|number" >
                     <requestFocus />
                 </EditText>
             </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                 android:id="@+id/linear_carga_manual_4"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/linear_carga_manual_3_5"
                 android:layout_marginTop="20dp" >

                 <TextView
                     android:id="@+id/title_trobat_article_traspas_manuall"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="-"
                     android:textColor="#70273D" />

             </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_carga_manual_4_5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/linear_carga_manual_4"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title_trobat_article_stock_manual_carga"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-"
                    android:textColor="#999999" />
            </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                 android:id="@+id/linear_carga_manual_5"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/linear_carga_manual_4_5"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                 android:layout_marginTop="91dp" >

                 <Button
                     android:id="@+id/boton_traspaso_manual"
                     style="@style/Botones"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="ACEPTAR" />
                 <Button
                     android:id="@+id/boton_traspaso_manual_cancelar"
                     style="@style/Botones"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="CANCELAR" />
             </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                 android:id="@+id/linear_carga_manual_6"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_below="@+id/linear_carga_manual_5"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                 android:layout_marginTop="30dp" >

                 <Button
                     android:id="@+id/boton_carga_manual_ver_carga"
                     style="@style/Botones"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:text="VER TRASPASO" />
             </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Mi Activity**

```
public class InventariManualProveedorAlmacenActivity extends Activity {


    private EditText article_edittext, cajas_edittext, unidades_edittext;
    private boolean accesodesdeboton = false;
    private ArticlesAlmacen article = null;
    private Button aceptar,cancelar, ver_traspaso;
    private RelativeLayout screenlayout;
    private TextView nomarticle;
    private boolean añadir = false;
    private String codiproveedor;
    int sizeorigi = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.traspaso_manual);
        DBalmacen = new ObrirBDAlmacen(getApplicationContext());
        article_edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_article_traspaso_manual);
        cajas_edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_cantidad_cajas_traspaso_manual);
        unidades_edittext = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_cantidad_unidades_traspaso_manual);
        nomarticle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title_trobat_article_traspas_manuall);
        aceptar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.boton_traspaso_manual);
        cancelar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.boton_traspaso_manual_cancelar);
        ver_traspaso = (Button)findViewById(R.id.boton_carga_manual_ver_carga);
        screenlayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.act_carga_manual_layout);
        listaarticles = Globals.getInstance().getLlistaArticlesPerTraspaso();
        sizeorigi = listaarticles.size();
        accesodesdeboton = Globals.getInstance().getAccesoDesdeBoton();
        codiproveedor = Globals.getInstance().getCodiProveidor();
        if (accesodesdeboton == true){
            article_edittext.requestFocus();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Acceso Desde Lista", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        article_edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (article_edittext.equals("")){
                    article_edittext.requestFocus();
                }
                else{
                    for (ArticlesAlmacen arti : listaarticles){
                        if (article_edittext.getText().toString().equals(arti.codiarticle) || article_edittext.getText().toString().equals(arti.ean13)){
                            nomarticle.setText(arti.codiarticle + " - " + arti.nom);
                            article = new ArticlesAlmacen();
                            article.codiarticle = arti.codiarticle;
                            article.unidadescaja = arti.unidadescaja;
                            article_edittext.setText(""+article.codiarticle);
                            break;
                        }
                        else{

                        }
                    }
                    if (article == null){
                        DBalmacen.open();
                        String codiarticlecodisbarres = DBalmacen.getArticleCodiBarresProveidor(article_edittext.getText().toString(), codiproveedor);
                        double unidadescajacodibarres = DBalmacen.getUnidadesCajaCodiBarres(article_edittext.getText().toString());
                        DBalmacen.close();
                        if (codiarticlecodisbarres == null){

                        }
                        else{
                            DBalmacen.open();
                            article = DBalmacen.getArticle(codiarticlecodisbarres);
                            nomarticle.setText(article.codiarticle + " - " + article.nom);
                            article_edittext.setText(""+article.codiarticle);
                            DBalmacen.close();
                            if (unidadescajacodibarres != 0){
                                article.unidadescaja = unidadescajacodibarres;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        cajas_edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (keyCode == 137 || keyCode == 141){ //KEY DE CODI DE BARRES
                    try{
                        cajas_edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                if (s.length()>4){
                                    cajas_edittext.setText("");
                                }

                            }

                        });
                    } catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

        });
        unidades_edittext.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (keyCode == 137 || keyCode == 141){ //KEY DE CODI DE BARRES
                    try{
                        unidades_edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

                            @Override
                            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                if (s.length()>4){
                                    unidades_edittext.setText("");
                                }

                            }

                        });
                    } catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                    aceptar.performClick();

                }
                return false;
            }

        });

        aceptar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                añadir = false;
                if (article != null){
                    if (cajas_edittext.getText().toString().length() == 0){
                        article.unipre = 0;
                    }
                    else{
                        article.unipre = Double.valueOf(cajas_edittext.getText().toString());
                    }
                    if (unidades_edittext.getText().toString().length() == 0){
                        article.unidad = 0;
                    }
                    else{
                        article.unidad = Double.valueOf(unidades_edittext.getText().toString());
                    }
                    for (ArticlesAlmacen arti : listaarticles){
                        if ((arti.codiarticle.equals(article.codiarticle)) && (arti.unidadescaja == article.unidadescaja)){
                            /*arti.unipre += article.unipre;
                            arti.unidad += article.unidad;*/

                            arti.unitatstotals += ((article.unipre*article.unidadescaja) + article.unidad);
                            arti.unipre = (int) (arti.unitatstotals / arti.unidadescaja);
                            arti.unidad = (int) (arti.unitatstotals % arti.unidadescaja);
                            añadir = true;

                        }
                    }
                    if (añadir == false && article != null){
                        //DIFERENTES UNITATS CAIXA
                        Log.e("Entro: " + article.unidadescaja, "Entro");
                        DBalmacen.open();
                        for (ArticlesAlmacen arti : listaarticles){
                            if ((arti.codiarticle.equals(article.codiarticle)) && (arti.unidadescaja != article.unidadescaja)){ 
                                /*arti.unipre += article.unipre;
                                arti.unidad += article.unidad;*/
                                double unidadescaja = DBalmacen.getUnidadesCajaArticle(article.codiarticle);
                                arti.unitatstotals += ((article.unipre*article.unidadescaja) + article.unidad);
                                arti.unipre = (int) (arti.unitatstotals /unidadescaja);
                                arti.unidad = (int) (arti.unitatstotals % unidadescaja);
                            }
                        }
                        DBalmacen.close();
                        //listaarticles.add(article);
                    }
                    for (ArticlesAlmacen arti : listaarticles){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + arti.unitatstotals, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                if (accesodesdeboton == true){
                    article = null;
                    article_edittext.setText("");
                    cajas_edittext.setText("");
                    unidades_edittext.setText("");
                    nomarticle.setText("-");
                    article_edittext.requestFocus();
                    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
                }
                añadir = false;
                Globals.getInstance().setTraspasoImprimido(0);
                article_edittext.requestFocus();
            }
        });
        cancelar.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                añadir = false;
                article = null;
                article_edittext.setText("");
                cajas_edittext.setText("");
                unidades_edittext.setText("");
                nomarticle.setText("-");
                article_edittext.requestFocus();
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, 0);
            }
        });
        /*ver_traspaso.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ArrayList<ArticlesAlmacen> listavertraspaso = new ArrayList<ArticlesAlmacen>();
                for (ArticlesAlmacen arti : copialistaarticles){
                    if (arti.unidad > 0 || arti.unipre > 0){
                        listavertraspaso.add(arti);
                    }
                }
                Globals.getInstance().setLlistaArticlesPerTraspaso(listavertraspaso);
                if (listavertraspaso.size()>0){
                    Intent i = new Intent(InventariManualAlmacenActivity.this, VerTraspasoActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No se encontraron lineas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

        });*/
    }
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (sizeorigi == listaarticles.size()){
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IGUAL SIZE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
        else{
            Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
            Globals.getInstance().setLlistaArticlesResult(listaarticles);
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DIFERENTE SIZE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
            finish();
        }
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_out2,R.anim.slide_in2);
    }

}
```

La idea es cuando presiono el botón Aceptar, quiero que el `artículo_edittext` reciba el foco (o cuando lo hago `aceptar.performClick ())`, pero siempre obtengo el foco en **cajas_edittext** después de agregar un artículo.

¿Puede alguien ayudarme por favor? He intentado muchas cosas pero estoy totalmente perdido en esto.

Comment: Hola Kevin, esto es StackOverlow español. Has de traducir tu pregunta o si la quieres hacer en inglés, hacerla en http://stackoverflow.com.

Comment: si tu idea es validar en un formulario, podrías hacer el llamado solo al requestfocus, solo en el metodo que se ejecuta al pulsar el botón y ahorrarte todos esos setOnFocusChangeListener

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner a tu `edit_cantidad_cajas_traspaso_manual` el `android:focusable` en `false`? Solo por ver que pasa

Comment: ¿Has probado a poner a tu edit_cantidad_cajas_traspaso_manual el android:focusable en false? Solo por ver que pasa En efecto, no he podido añadirlo como comentario porqué aún no tengo reputación suficiente para responderte allí, pero era lo que me ocurría y no lo había visto, lo había pasado por alto.

Comment: @cnbandicoot añade la respuesta, ese era el problema

Comment: Si deshabilitas el enfoque a la vista "edit_cantidad_cajas_traspaso_manual" probablemente tengas problemas ya que seguramente esta vista necesite el enfoque, agregue una respuesta @Kevin

Comment: Lo que se debe realizar es requerir el enfoque en la vista deseada por medio del método requestFocus() @Kevin deshabilitar el enfoque en otras vistas sería solución como "tener una fuga y cerrar el agua para solucionarlo, siendo que posteriormente necesites tomar agua" =).

Answer (score 2):

Ponle a tu EditText en el que se hace focus el `focusable` en `false`:

```
 <EditText
 android:id="@+id/edit_cantidad_cajas_traspaso_manual"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:inputType="numberSigned|number|numberDecimal"
 android:ems="3"
 android:maxLength="6"
 android:focusable="false" ◄ aquí
 android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
 android:hint="0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que se realiza es requerir el enfoque en la vista deseada, esto después de la acción click por medio del método [requestFocus()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus()) :

```
artículo_edittext.requestFocus()
```

en algunos casos se requiere de un handler para que funcione correctamente.

```
 mHandler.post(
       new Runnable() 
       {
          public void run() 
          {
            artículo_edittext.requestFocus() 
          } 
       }
     );
```

no recomiendo deshabilitar permitir el foco en otros `EditText` como `cajas_edittext` ya que seguramente requerira en algún momento del enfoque, *si estas seguro de no requerir en ningún momento del enfoque en esta vista*, simplemente deshabilita esta propiedad mediante `android:focusable="false"`.

```
       <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_cantidad_cajas_traspaso_manual"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberSigned|number|numberDecimal"
            android:ems="3"
            android:maxLength="6"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:hint="0" />
```